# What's the difference between void, eval, and the Function constructor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eval, void, ecmascript-5, function-constructor

```js
void(document.body.innerText += 'hi')

eval(document.body.innerText +='\nbye')

Function(document.body.innerText += '\n!!!')

void(Function(function foo(){document.body.innerText += '\n>hi2'; return true}).toString())();

eval(Function(function foo(){document.body.innerText += '\nbye2'; return true}).toString())();

Function(Function(function foo(){document.body.innerText += '\n!!!2'; return true}).toString())();
```

What's the processing model for executing code within these different statements?

```
void(alert('hi'))
undefined

eval(alert('hi'))
undefined

Function(alert('hi'))
function anonymous() {
  undefined
}

eval(Function(function foo(){return true}).toString())();
TypeError: undefined is not a function

void(Function(function foo(){return true}).toString())();
TypeError: string is not a function

Function(Function(function foo(){return true}).toString())();
undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/) the `eval` and `Function` constructors are explained:

> (…) Global, built-in `eval` function **evaluates code in the scope of a
>   caller**.
>
> The code executed from within function created by `Function` constructor
>   doesn’t really execute in global scope. However, it doesn’t execute in
>   local scope either, which is what probably leads to confusion.
>   `Function` constructor creates a function whose scope chain consists of
>   nothing but a global scope (preceded with function’s own Activation
>   Object, of course). Any code contained in a function created via
>   `Function` constructor **evaluates in a scope of that function, not in a
>   global scope**. However, it’s almost as if code executes globally, since
>   global object is the very next object in the scope chain.

And according to [this page](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html), `void` just returns `undefined`:

> In many languages, `void` is a type that has no values. In JavaScript,
>   `void` is an operator that takes an operand and returns `undefined`. This
>   is not useful, and it is very confusing. Avoid `void`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a summary of the evaluation differences:

- `void` evaluates code in the containing function scope
- `eval` evaluates strings in the containing function scope
- `Function` evaluates code in its own scope

and the return differences:

- `void` always returns undefined
- `eval` returns the return value of the executed code
- `Function` returns an anonymous function

**References**

- [JS101: The Function Constructor](http://dailyjs.com/2012/07/09/function-2/)
- [JSLint Error Explanations: The Function constructor is eval](http://jslinterrors.com/the-function-constructor-is-eval)
- [How Evil is Eval](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)
- [[[Scope]] of functions created via Function constructor](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-4-scope-chain/#scope-of-functions-created-via-function-constructor)
- [Evaluating JavaScript code via eval() and new Function()](http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html)
- [Gmail for Mobile HTML5 Series: Reducing Startup Latency - The official Google Code blog](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/09/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-reducing.html)
- [Faster Loading Through Eval() – SproutCore](http://blog.sproutcore.com/faster-loading-through-eval/)
- [(down)Loading JavaScript as strings | High Performance Web Sites](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/12/07/downloading-javascript-as-strings/)
- [Expressions versus statements in JavaScript - Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)
- [The void operator in JavaScript](http://www.2ality.com/2011/05/void-operator.html)

Comment: `void` does not evaluate code in the global scope. `void expr` evaluates `expr` just like `expr` alone would do, and it happens in the current scope. it's not like `eval` or `Function` at all, which evaluate a string as code.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that **you are completely misusing these functions**.

- `void` just evaluates some expression and returns undefined.

  Note it's an operator and not a function, so no need to wrap the operant inside parentheses.

  This is only useful to get the value undefined if you worry `undefined` could be shadowed, or if you want to type less characters.

  Instead of

  ```
  var undef = void(document.body.innerText += 'hi')
  ```

  better use

  ```
  document.body.innerText += 'hi';
  var undef = void 0;
  ```

  And if you don't need to get undefined, don't use `void` at all.
- `eval` is supposed to be called with a string. It evaluates that string as code. The exact behavior depends on whether you call it in strict or sloppy mode, and whether it's a direct or indirect call.

  If you don't call it with a string, it will just return the argument.

  In your case, `eval(document.body.innerText += '\nbye')` will:

  1. Run `document.body.innerText += '\nbye'`, returns the new value, e.g. `"hello\nbye"`.
  2. Evaluate the resulting text as code. Most probably this will throw.

  I'm almost sure `eval(document.body.innerText +='\nbye')` is not what you want, but here is a (not recommended) counterexample:

  ```js
  var myvar = 0;
  var bye = 123
  eval(document.body.innerText += '\nbye');
  console.log(myvar); // 123
  ```

  ```html
  myvar =
  ```
- The `Function` constructor is basically like `eval`, but it creates a function instead of running the evaluating the string as code immediately.

  `document.body.innerText += '\n!!!'` can't return a valid string, so it will just throw.
- Then you have some strange mixes of these functions.

  If you pass a function to the `Function` constructor, it will be stringified. The `Function` constructor will return an anonymous function that will just declare a function like the argument. It's pointless.

  If you call `toString`, this will stringify the anonymous function.

  Then, `void(Function(function foo(){document.body.innerText += '\n>hi2'; return true}).toString())();` will attempt to call this stringification. But strings are not callable. Error.

  And `eval(Function(function foo(){document.body.innerText += '\nbye2'; return true}).toString())();` will evaluate the stringification. Just why? But function declarations don't return a value, so you will just get undefined, which is not callable. Error.

  And `Function(Function(function foo(){document.body.innerText += '\n!!!2'; return true}).toString())();` will stringify `foo`, parse it to an anonymous function, stringify the anonymous function, and parse it again to another anonymous function. Please, don't do this. Finally, the call will return undefined because there is no return statement in there.